# Any reason not to use bcrypt on email addresses?

Tags: php, security, authentication, bcrypt

Login form I'm working on right now uses user email address and password to login.
So I was thinking, is there any reason why I shouldn't want to use bcrypt on email addresses as:

```
$email_hash = password_hash($email, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

I know it's intended for passwords, but so what? Should work on emails as well... If email is used to login, shouldn't it be hashed/salted just like the password? I know this isn't a standard practice, but never understood why.

I don't necessarily need to know user's email addresses. I mean, it's not like I'm gonna chat with them. Maybe when a user gets banned I should inform them by email, but why bother informing outlaws in the first place.

Comment: No reason not to, save for cost. If someone hacks your database they will not be able to get the email addresses out - neither will you. So, if you need the user's email addresses for something else you would be hosed.

Comment: Emails are used for communication. If you hash the email addresses of all your users, how will you ever be able to contact them with sites news/updates/password resets, etc? No need for it. If you're worried about your database getting jacked, just make sure you keep the software up-to-date, and use the plethora of others security-based measures to keep that from happening.

Comment: You need the user name (email address) in order to be able to log in. If you hash the user name using `password_hash`, you'll get a different value each time, so the only way to find the user record is to try each hash and see if that matches.

Comment: The reason @Arjan provided is the best reason not to.

Comment: @Arjan the obvious solution there would be to use `password_verify()` for the email address too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the email address to lookup the user record.

Typically you do something like this:

```
function create_account(email, password) {
    var pwhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    // insert into users values ($email, $pwhash);
}

function login(email, password) {
    // select pwhash from users where email = $email;
    return password_verify($password, $pwhash); // true or false
}
```

`password_hash($email)` will always return a different value because bcrypt includes a salt in the hash.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt):

> For example, the [bcrypt hash] $2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy specifies a cost parameter of 10, indicating 210 key expansion rounds. The salt is N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMye and the resulting hash is IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy.

Or from [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

> Note that password_hash() returns the algorithm, cost and salt as part of the returned hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the verify function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

Comment: By the by, this was a PHP question and you gave a Node.js answer. :)

Comment: I think I've properly PHP'ized this pseudocode now.

Comment: But you could use `password_verify($email, $emailHash)` for the email as well, no?

Comment: You could but then you'd have to iterate through all users in the database to do so because you'd have no way to know which $emailHash to use.